# GitLab Server where to find hard deleted unpushed commit

Tags: visual-studio, gitlab, commit

My push operation failed, due to my colleague commited one line to the same branch i was working on, and i forgot to stash mine, so i tried to revert my colleague's commit and copy it into my changes, that way only an outgoing commit would have existed, i thought. It didn't work out the way i wanted, so i tried to reset his commit, and i right clicked the commit and then clicked Reset->Delete --Hard (in visual studio), which deleted all of his and my commit.

Again I did commit my changes, only i failed to push it to the server. I found the `git reflog` command, but i am not sure if i can use it without using a Git desktop client.

Is there a way to find my unpushed commit from the server using SSH client? Or should I just rewrite everything? About 50-100 rows of code have been lost.

**SOLVED:**

Use Visual Studio Git menu near the upper left corner -> Open in command prompt then

```
git reflog
```

then

```
git cherry-pick <SHA-1>
```

where SHA-1 is the head of the branch (e.g. HEAD@{1}) as described in the link below in user1686 answer's.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `git reflog` or `git fsck --unreachable` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035998/deleted-branch-unexpectedly-git-in-visual-studio can find recently-lost commits.

However, recovery methods need to be run on a repository where those commits *were* visible previously. If a commit wasn't successfully pushed, then it won't be on the Git server at all – the only place it'll be in is your local Git repository in VS.

(Although there may be a "reflog" on the server repository too, it would only get updated if the push was successful. For example, SSH could be used to recover commits that were successfully pushed but got overwritten by a later force-push – but not those that were rejected outright.)

> I found the 'git reflog' command, but i am not sure if i can use it without using a Git desktop client.

'git reflog' is from the [Git command-line tools](https://git-scm.com/downloads), which are usually bundled with most Git desktop clients, but are not actually tied to any app.

You're already using a Git desktop client – Visual Studio – which also installs a copy of Git, so it should be enough to `cd` to your source directory and run `git` from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. I managed to get back my lost commit! Saved a lot of time for me. 

I used the Visual Studio Git menu near the upper left corner -> Open in command prompt then 'git reflog' then 'git cherry-pick <SHA-1>' as described in the link above.